# Identify markers in larger images/photographs

Tags: image-recognition

my overall goal is recognition of similar, reflective and low-textured monochrome objects in a controlled museum-like-environment. These objects are well designed and visually appealing.

For my understanding this goal is too high aimed when i look at contemporary object and image recognition software like goggles, kooaba, tineye etc..

So i was thinking of placing little markers on the objects and identify the markers.
In order to employ AR tracking software the markers need to be black/white and ugly. That would spoil the visual appearance of the objects i'd like to identify.

Do you know of any software that recognizes (arbitrary designed / visually appealing) markers in photographs?

Or; do you think this can be accomplished with openCV for iOS/android devices?

Answer (score 1):

You already name the major problems for goggles,kooaba,etc.: similarity, reflections, low-textured areas.

> Do you know of any software that recognizes (arbitrary designed / visually appealing) markers in photographs?

Yes: goggles, kooaba, tineye etc

That is, as long as your "arbitrary designed / visually appealing" markers are textured, not too much similar and don´t reflect.

For example, if your scenario is in a museum with images of black/white low-textured similar objects behind glass and you don´t mind putting a colored marker next to the image, try pictures of animals (comic-like or so)... with a modern image recognition setup you can use these pictures as markers. Or put up like an information stand next to the object, which has some marker on it.